# Mount ISO from windows startup repair menu

Tags: windows, boot, iso-image

**BACKGROUND**

I have been experiencing some startup issues on my windows system recently and it has led to my pc not booting up at all. It just shows the windows logo and gets stuck. I reboot the pc and it launches automatic repair which always fails leading me to other options.

**SCENARIO**

I have a windows 10 iso file in that drive. I would like to copy the files in that ISO using the `xcopy` command to another drive so I can install windows on it. To do that I would have to mount the ISO on a specific drive letter and then perform the copy operation.

**QUESTION**

How do I mount the ISO file from this environment? I try using `PowerShell Mount-DiskImage` but it just returns null. Any ideas?

Comment: When the computer goes to Startup Repair, there should be a menu choice that allows you to reinstall Windows and keep the data. I have used this choice before.  If there is sufficient damage you cannot do that, then boot with a bootable USB key, recover the data you need and then use the Windows ISO to reinstall Windows. I have seen this error and situation you describe when the disk has failed.

Comment: I tried the reinstall windows option and that fails as well. What I want to do now is use cmd to copy the files from the ISO image to another disk. If I can get that done, I think I'll be good.

Comment: Get the computer manufacturer's diagnostic app and test the hard drive to see if it works.

Comment: Btw, i also do not have a bootable usb key.

Comment: You can make a bootable USB key with the Windows ISO and Rufus. Rufus can make a USB bootable.

Comment: Just a reminder to make a disk image *before* you try to reinstall Windows, to avoid loss of personal files. You can do that from a bootable USB, e.g. Macrium Reflect's or Ubuntu Live with *dd*. Yes, I saw that you don't have such a drive now,  but perhaps a friend can create it.